# CSS - Bootstrap overriding font - CSS is minified with custom CSS at the bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, gulp

I have a simple HTML page which I am using Bootstrap with and I am trying to use some custom CSS for the font of the page.

I am using Gulp to put all CSS into one file and minify it so the end result is a single .CSS file which has both bootstrap and my custom CSS in (Is this not recommended?)

My site works locally but when I push it to the dev web server (Using the dist/ folder) it seems to default to a generic sans-serfi font not the Google Font which using Chrome Developer tools I can see that it does not generate a 404 for the Google Font and it shows that rule is applied but that is not the font I specified.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>MooWoos Stall Booking</title>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel='stylesheet' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--build:css css/styles.min.css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <!--endbuild-->

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
        <a class="logo"><img src="assets/logo_opt.png" alt="MooWoos Stall Booking"></a>
    </nav>

    <hr>

    <div class="modal fade" id="redirect_page" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="form-horizontal">

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <div>Booking successful! Redirecting to PayPal... </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="submit_error" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="form-horizontal">

                    <div class="modal-body alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <div>Error submitting the form. Please contact MooWoos Directly.</div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 bookingform">
            <h1>Stall Booking Form</h1>
            <p class="lead">
                Fill out the form to book and pay for your stall!
            </p>
            <form id="bookingForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                <!-- BELOW ARE PAYPAL FIELDS FROM PAYPAL GENERATION -->
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                <input type="hidden" id="hosted_button_id" name="hosted_button_id" value="js_value">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name </label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" value="" title="Please enter your name" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="address">Address </label>
                    <textarea id="address" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Address" title="Please enter your address" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phone">Telephone Number </label>
                    <input type="tel" id="phone" pattern="(([0]{1})|([\+][4]{2}))([1]|[2]|[3]|[7]){1}\d{9}$" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Telephone Number" value="" title="Please enter the best telephone number to contact you on" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email </label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" value="" title="Please enter your Email address" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    Which date would you like to book?
                    <p></p>
                    <p><input type="radio" name="date" value="13th September" required/> Sunday 13th September</p>
                    <p><input type="radio" name="date" value="6th February" /> Saturday 6th February</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>What type of stall do you require?</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="stallType" id="stallType-Preloved" value="Preloved" required>
                        <label for="stallType-Preloved">Preloved</label>
                        <div class="reveal-if-active form-inline">
                            Will you be bringing a clothes rail?
                            <label class="stallLabel" for="c-rail-yes">Yes</label> <input type="radio" id=c-rail-yes name="c-rail" value="Yes" />
                            <label class="stallLabel" for="c-rail-no">No</label> <input type="radio" id=c-rail-no name="c-rail" value="No" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="stallType" id="stallType-Craft" value="Craft">
                        <label for="stallType-Craft">Craft</label>
                        <div class="reveal-if-active">
                            <label for="craftName">What name do you use?</label>
                            <input type="text" id="craftName" name="craftName" class="require-if-active form-control" placeholder="Craft Name" title="Please provide us with your Craft name" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="stallType" id="stallType-Business" value="Business">
                        <label for="stallType-Business">Business</label>
                        <div class="reveal-if-active">
                                <label for="bizName">What is your business name?</label>
                                <input type="text" id="bizName" name="bizName" class="require-if-active form-control" placeholder="Business Name" title="Please provide us with your Business name" value="" />
                                <br>
                                Do you have Public Liability Insurance?
                                <label class="insuranceLabel" for="insurance-yes">Yes</label> <input type="radio" id="insurance-yes" name="insurance" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#stallType-Business" title="We will require proof of this prior to market day" value="Yes"/>
                                <label class="insuranceLabel" for="insurance-no">No</label> <input type="radio" id="insurance-no" name="insurance" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#stallType-Business" title="Our insurance does not cover other businesses. Please ensure you have adequate cover and provide us with proof prior to market day" value="No"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="items">What type of items will you be selling?</label>
                        <input type="text" id="items" class="form-control" placeholder="Girls age 3-5, Toys mixed etc.." title="Please enter the type of items you will be selling" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Book & Pay" />
                    </div>
            </form>
            <p></p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <hr>

    <footer>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>Copyright &copy; MooWoos 2018. Booking Form by Luke Brewerton</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </footer>

</div>

<!--build:js js/mwbookings-min.js -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.serialize-object.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

</body>
</html>
```

style.scss:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700,800');

body {
  font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
}

.reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: 0.5s;
  input[type="radio"]:checked ~ &,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ & {
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.stallLabel {
  clear:right;
  text-align:center;
  padding-right:5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.insuranceLabel {
  clear:right;
  text-align:center;
  padding-right:5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Also below is my Gulpfile incase I am doing something wrong in there:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    sass        = require('gulp-sass'),
    minifyCss   = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    uglify      = require('gulp-uglify'),
    concat      = require('gulp-concat'),
    useref      = require('gulp-useref'),
    gulpIf      = require('gulp-if'),
    cssnano     = require('gulp-cssnano'),
    notify      = require('gulp-notify');


// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Move the javascript files into our /src/js folder
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/js"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

//Compile and minify CSS and JS
gulp.task('compile', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/index.html')
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
});

//Copy all assets to Dist folder
gulp.task('assets', function () {
    gulp.src('src/assets/**.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets'));
})

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['sass','js'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./src"
    });

    gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("src/js/*.js").on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("src/css/*.css").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

//Builds the Dist folder for production
gulp.task('build', ['sass','js','assets','compile'], function () {
    gulp.src('dist/**.*')
    .pipe(notify({
        title   :   'Build finished!',
        message :   'Site compiled and ready for Production!'
    }));
});

gulp.task('default', ['js','serve']);
```

I sue the `gulp build` task on the dev web server to populate the `dist/` folder which nginx reads.

All my other custom CSS is applying, just not the font.

Comment: Where exactly Bootstrap overwrites your font call? Open the inspector and see if is in the body or in a specific tag

Comment: It is under `body`, It shows the Bootstrap rule as corssed out but if I untick my rule it goes to the Bootstrap rule like it is suing my rule but the font definitely isn't correct.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome & Firefox

Comment: Have you tried remove the gulp function (I never used it so I can't see if the problem is in it) and remove the other css, leave just the font call?

Comment: The Gulp is manual and all it does is minify the CSS to remove excess whitesapce. Removing other CSS would render the rest of the page wrong, or removing the bootstrap font call but that would affect BS.

Comment: I know, but just for testing, removing the others css and see if the font called normal, otherwise, try removing gulp minify, removing things to discover where is the problem understand?

Comment: Without the minification it is working correctly so it seems to be an issue with the minification.

Comment: It may be because the @import rule should be at the beginning of the css file - are you concatenating the bootstrap and style.css together, with your style.css second?  Can you just reverse the order?  I don't see a concatenate call in your gulpfile.js though.

Comment: I would suggest using the <link> method instead of @import to include your font file.

Comment: If the solution from @Mark doesn't work, try to minify the css manually or than unminy the css, put it in your editor, and see if it shows up the error